# Download S3 File Using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm currently writing a script in where I need to download S3 files to a created directory. I currently create a boto3 session with credentials, create a boto3 resource from that session, then use it to query and download from my s3 location. It looks something like the example below:

```
s3_session = boto3.Session(...)
s3_resource = s3_session.resource('s3')

mnt_loc = '/home/username/tmp/'

s3_loc = urlparse('s3://bucket_name/path1/path2/', allow_fragments=False)
s3_files = []
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(s3_loc.netloc)
for elem in bucket.objects:
    s3_files.append(elem)

for elem in s3_files:
    s3_resource.Bucket(elem.bucket_name).download_file(elem.key, mnt_loc + elem.key.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])
```

In theory, I thought this would copy the specified file from the s3 location to my mount location while keeping the naming of the file. When executing, I'm getting an

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: /home/username/tmp/filename.csv.F2H1nxR0.

Why isn't this process working and also, why is the process appending these random strings to the end of my file name like the 'F2H1nxR0' shown?

Comment: Hi JMV12, on the last line can you rewrite as this?
```bucket.download_file(elem.key, mnt_loc + elem.key.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])```
Also, what is the content of elem when you get the error?

Comment: What is the contents of `elem` when it fails?

Comment: The content of elem is 

    s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='bucket_name', key='/path1/path2/filename_1.csv')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way to correct the error I was receiving. The issue was I was passing the s3.ObjectSummary parts into my download_file(). To fix this error, I converted all the parts to string as shown below:

```
s3_session = boto3.Session(...)
s3_resource = s3_session.resource('s3')

mnt_loc = '/home/username/tmp/'

s3_loc = urlparse('s3://bucket_name/path1/path2/', allow_fragments=False)
s3_files = []
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(s3_loc.netloc)
for elem in bucket.objects:
    s3_files.append(elem)

for elem in s3_files:
    bucket = str(elem.bucket_name)
    path = str(elem.key)
    file_name = str(elem.key.rsplit('/', 1)[-1])
    s3_resource.Bucket(bucket).download_file(path, mnt_loc + file_name)
```

This eliminated the [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /home/username/tmp/filename.csv.F2H1nxR0 and gets rid of the 8 character string appended to the end of the file name. Thank you everyone for your help as it lead me to finding this fix.